# What version of Nancy package can we use for asp.net core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, .net-core, nancy

Not sure where to put this question but currently I'm interested in **NancyFX** for asp.net core 2.0 i have tried to use both *2.0.0-Pre1878* version and *2.0.0-clinteastwood* without much luck. Has anyone managed to use these? Is there a reference application for me to play with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" /> 
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.0.0" /> 
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin" Version="2.0.0" /> 
  <PackageReference Include="Nancy" Version="2.0.0-clinteastwood" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

(specifically notice you need `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin`)

> Is there a reference application for me to play with?

Yes.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/samples/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Kestrel

Minimal example:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Owin;

namespace HelloNancy
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

      host.Run();
    }
  }

  public class Startup
  {
    private readonly IConfiguration config;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
      config = builder.Build();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
      app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy(opt => opt.Bootstrapper = new DemoBootstrapper()));
    }
  }

  public class DemoBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
  {
    public DemoBootstrapper()
    {
    }
  }

  public class SampleModule : Nancy.NancyModule
  {
    public SampleModule()
    {
      Get("/", _ => "Hello World!");
    }
  }
}
```

(specifically notice that you should use kestrel with core, not self hosting, as `Nancy.Hosting.Self` targets 4.6, not netstandard)